# Drupal+Ubercart: Get product list

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

Does anyone here knows how I could get the list of products including image paths so I could manually process them without using Views?

Comment: It would be useful for exporting products too, since there is no mass exporter functionality built in, nor there is any plugin for it AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own mysql queries or use Drupal's framework to launch your customer queries.  Something like:

```
<?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM uc_products WHERE YOUR_WHERE_CLAUSE_HERE";
 $result=db_query($query);
 print mysql_result($result, 0); 
 // you probably want to loop through the $result array

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   echo "Product Title = " . $row['title_field'];
   echo "Image Url = " . $row['image_url'];
 }  
?>
```

Other tables related to Ubercart that may help:

```
uc_product_classes
uc_product_features
```

Put this code in a `block` or `page` or wherever you are trying to do it.